# Ruby arrays: right hand of statement changing through assignment even though I didn't tell it to

Tags: ruby

I am doing some work with nested for loops. I want an array called holdRotated to be populated with certain elements in holdSmallerArea. However, during this assignment, for some reason, holdSmallerArea has changed, even though I didn't tell it to.

```
puts holdSmallerArea
holdRotated[i][j] = holdSmallerArea[holdRotated.length - j - 1][i]
puts holdSmallerArea

Out:
123
456
789

723
456
789
```

As you can see in my code, I have not told holdSmallerArea to change, so why is it printing different things out?

Full code:

```
$maze=
  ["123",
  "456",
  "789",]

def plot x,y,distance
  holdSmallerArea = []
  holdRotated = []
  rows = []
  for i in 0..2 do
    for j in 0..2 do
      rows << $maze[i][j]
    end
    rows = rows.join('')
    holdSmallerArea << rows
    holdRotated << rows
    rows = []
  end

  for i in (0..(holdRotated.length - 1)) do
      for j in (0..(holdRotated.length - 1)) do
        puts holdSmallerArea
        holdRotated[i][j] = holdSmallerArea[holdRotated.length - j - 1][i]
        puts holdSmallerArea
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: How have you defined holdSmallerArea and holdRotated? Can you please post more code

Comment: Because `holdSmallerArea` and `holdRotated` reference same object in the memory. Did you do this somewhere before `holdRotated = holdSmallerArea`?

Comment: @Fabio I have updated the question. As you can see I created 2 different arrays and populated them separately, to try to overcome the passing by reference issue

Comment: I guess the final object instances are passed by reference, you need to make a copy if you've got mutable object instances. Or you could make them immutable of course and return a changed copy on any operation.

Comment: Can you show full sample? What happens around where you trying to print arrays out?

Comment: @Fabio I have put the full code above. As you can see all I am doing is changing values with nested for loops. The purpose of this algorithm is to rotate the maze array on its side which I am trying to implement.

Comment: You are setting the same array `rows` for `holdSmallerArea` and `holdRotated`

Comment: @Aguardientico Thank you, I used the clone method to copy data from rows instead of assigning it and it worked!

Comment: Right approach would be to use 2 dimensional arrays instead of string, because string is mutable in ruby.